# Calculating sum of children's balance for each parent

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables having parent-child relationship

```
Table1
| Account_no | Main_account_no | bla bla
+------------+-----------------+----------
|     234    |        111      |  
|     235    |        111      |  
|     222    |        112      |  
|     220    |        112      |
```

The second:

```
Table2
| Account_no | Balance         | bla bla
+------------+-----------------+----------
|     234    |        10       |  
|     235    |        15       |  
|     222    |        55       |  
|     220    |        45       |
```

What I need is to calculate the sum of balance of child accounts for each parent account.
The expected result is

```
| Main_account_no | Balance |
+-----------------+---------+
| 111             |  35     |
| 112             |  100    |
```

I am trying to use

```
SELECT MAIN_ACCOUNT_NO, SUM((SELECT BALANCE FROM TABLE2 WHERE ACCOUNT_NO = A.ACCOUNT_NO)) OVER (PARTITION BY MAIN_ACCOUNT_NO)
FROM TABLE1 A
GROUP BY MAIN_ACCOUNT_NO
```

But I get the `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with Oracle, but your statement defeats the purpose of a group by. You're asking each row to run another query to pull the sum for you. I don't want to give too much away because I suspect this is homework :-)

Comment: I'd start by ignoring the aggregation and making a query that gives you a table with 3 columns; `main_account_no, account_no, balance` — then you can add the group by to that.

Comment: hm you are right using `group by` seems useless, I will  try your suggested approach, and it is not a homework

Comment: `Group By` is correct, it's the select bit in `sum(select....)` that's useless (it will cause an extra select query for every row).

Comment: So table1 is the account table with `account_no` being the primary key? And what is table2's primary key? Can there really be just one record per account, as you are showing? If so, why is this a separate table?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes table1's PK is account_no, table2's PK is also `account_no`, they are separated because they hold completely different data in each table in big amounts, there may be other reasons too, I didn't design the tables I am only generating a report based on multiple of this tables

Comment: Then I guess the only flaw in your query is the `OVER` clause. I don't know why you even put this in your query. Remove it an you should be fine.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes seems like I read too much about window functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this apparently isn't homework... :-)

First let's get the main_account_nos alongside the balances:

```
select
    Table1.Main_account_no,
    Table1.Account_no,
    Table2.Balance
from
    Table1
    join Table2 on Table1.Account_no = Table2.Account_no
```

Gives

```
| Main_account_no | Account_no | Balance         |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
|        111      |     234    |        10       |
|        111      |     235    |        15       |
|        112      |     222    |        55       |
|        112      |     220    |        45       |
```

Now we can easily group as required:

```
select
    Table1.Main_account_no,
    sum(Table2.Balance) as total
from
    Table1
    join Table2 on Table1.Account_no = Table2.Account_no
group by
    Table1.Main_account_no
```